Linear regression on OpenCV coordinates system
I'm making a trajectory prediction of an air hockey disk using a cam and OpenCV to collect points and then calculate the prediction with a linear regression. I have a problem where I visually get a pretty good result but
I used this code to provide the (x,y) output and plot a line that starts from the center of the disk towards the predicted y which should cross x = width. Given a list of points points[]
    a = 0
    sum_x = 0
    sum_y = 0
    sumSquare_x = 0

    n = len(points)

    for point in points:

        a += point[0] * point[1]
        sum_x += point[0]
        sum_y += point[1]
        sumSquare_x += point[0] ** 2
    
    a *= n
    b = sum_x * sum_y
    c = n * sumSquare_x
    d = sum_x ** 2
    
    m = -(a - b) / (c - d) if (c - d) != 0 else 0
    x = width
    q = (center_y - m * center_x)
    y = height - int(m * x + q) 
    
    cv2.line(frame, (center_x, center_y), (x, y), (0, 255, 0), 5)
    print(x, y) 

This is the output

3448 -145
3448 -141
3448 -105
3448 -97
3448 -78
3448 -54 


3448 1038
3448 991
3448 983
3448 961
3448 938
3448 919


3448 -44
3448 -586
3448 -494
3448 -417
3448 -401
3448 -353


Nice Question, can you focus your code into the problematic part? Also, it seems like you have some indentation problems. Why are you returning 0 in python?

@TinoD The main problem are the y values that drops everything into the rebounding loop, so I would focus on that. But maybe I’m collecting the points badly. I’m returning 0 because I want to differentiate between 0 = no error and other numbers = error; is it bad practice?

may I suggest that you improve the title? I think it doesn't describe the issue. -- also, don't forget to debug your code, visualize ever more things until you see what's happening. pin the problem down. so far, it looks like a problem with your code exclusively, with no way to shift blame to OpenCV.

@ChristophRackwitz Thanks for the advice. I tried to print the value to try to understand where the problem is and I’m pretty sure it has to do something with how I manage the calculations for the linear regression. I still can’t see the problem after many tries and I’m thinking that maybe I’m missing something from the mathematical point of view

I presume you realise that you specify the y axis coordinate first, followed by the x axis coordinate? You access a point as image[distance from top, distance from left]

@MarkSetchell So are you telling me it is all flipped?

I'm just telling you how it is. Whether you, or anyone else considers it flipped depends on their frame of reference.

Make a 100x100 black image with im =np.zeros((100,100), np.uint8) then draw a white square with im[90:99, 0:9] = 255 and see where the square appears.

Proper [mcve] needed, problem is likely in code not shown. I have a feeling Mark is onto it, tho.

seconding the call for MRE. -- I see no indexing (i,j / y,x) going on. whatever OP describes could be wilder than a mere flip around a diagonal axis. I can't even figure out the description. too much "business logic" going on here.

@MarkSetchell The square appears bottom left. Also, I added probably clearer information to the question

Hopefully you see that the first index is the distance from the top, i.e. the y coordinate.

@MarkSetchell Yes, so how does it affect my code?

I don't know. It is not a [mcve].

@MarkSetchell I completely rephrased the question I hope it is more clear now for everyone

@TinoD I edited everything should be more clear

points is undefined. please define it. you seem to be summing stuff up. what for? refactor the code and create functions that convey the meaning.
